AWS Lightsail: I still get 404 errors despite copying index.html to 404.html
I'm deploying a website onto AWS Lightsail. Within htdocs I copied index.html into 404.html. However, when I go to a random resource like this:
mysite.com/nonexistant
I get 404: Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.
Does anyone know why this is? I should be routed to index.html and displayed the homepage

What web server are you using? Apache and Nginx are most common. Have you configured the web server to use your 404 page? If so, please include config. You usually have to reload / restart the web server to pick up changes.

@Tim I am not sure about this. Can you point me to resources? I am using default aws lightsail which uses bitnami. They don't specify if it's apache or not

I think you have some learning to do. Unfortunately we can't help you with this little information. Bitnami is a company, they release a variety of products that are easy to deploy on Lightsail.
